# Ping piped to txt does output nothing

Tags: windows-7, ping, cmd.exe, pipe

Following script should pipe the ping output to a text file

```
@echo off
rem end with ctrl+c y
ping 192.168.33.65 -t >> C:\_ScriptLog\Ping\ping.txt
```

but nothing is piped to the txt file, it´s empty.

EDIT:

If I start this command (without echo off and rem) directly from cmd it works...

Comment: If the file exists, your script will work - no problem with it! Try  to write something like "echo MyTest >> C:\_ScriptLog\Ping\ping.txt"

Comment: actually, the file exits... it just does not work

Comment: Try taking off `-t` - does that work? If so, then the problem is that the output doesn't get forwarded until the command is completed - with `-t`, the command will effectively never complete.

Comment: Check if the file is writable.

Comment: that actually solved it, i didn´t had the rights to write into the file, just to read it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the file is writable. Open it with Notepad, type something and try to save.

If saving fails, you have to add write permissions for your account. This can be done in file's properties, *Security* tab.

<sub>(I've originally suggested this in comments and OP confirmed it was the culprit.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Is the output from ping going to [stderr rather than stdout](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930)? If so, this should work:

```
@echo off
rem end with ctrl+c y
ping 192.168.33.65 -t 1>> C:\_ScriptLog\Ping\ping.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: does only write the "do you want to abort the batch?(y/n)" message to the textfile...